# Order totals including tax in order totals [OpenCart]

Tags: opencart

I have prices in my store including 20% TAX. The problem is with order totals, let me explain.

Default view in OpenCart (shipping cost is 3€ incl. TAX):

```
Product X ........................1,50 EUR
------------------------------------------
Shipping  ........................2,50 EUR

Subtotal without tax..............1,25 EUR
TAX 20%...........................0,75 EUR
Total (incl Tax)..................4,50 EUR
```

The problem is:

- subtotal does not includes shipping cost = confusing
- shipping cost is displayed without TAX = confusing

Expected result:

```
Product X ........................1,50 EUR
------------------------------------------
Shipping  ...........................3 EUR

Subtotal without tax..............3,75 EUR
TAX 20%...........................0,75 EUR
Total (incl Tax)..................4,50 EUR
```

Is there any way to display order totals as I showed?

Comment: Thats is only for the cart right. You basically want tax +subtotal

Comment: Where the order total is displayed (cart, order info). It is managed by /catalog/model/total/*. Basically I need: show shipping with tax (at this moment it is displayed without TAX) + want subtotal with shipping cost (at this moment subtotal is displayed without shipping).

Comment: Are you using a cart module? hence usually you don't see shipping in your cart you have to choose it afterwards in a lower step? unless you are using some 1 page module?

Comment: In the settings there is an option show prices with tax just choose yes. Go visit https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=1963 & https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?p=98663 hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why this super old question hasn't been answered but in case anyone still cares, here you go (for Opencart v1.5 but you could easily adapt these concepts for newer versions)...

In order to preserve the actual cost calcs I'm only going to be manipulating the *displayed amount* for each total.  The underlying value will stay as is, which will save us from needing to make any adjustment to the calculations and possibly affecting other parts of the totals in an undesired way.

To show shipping with tax, in **catalog/model/total/shipping**, change:

```
'text' => $this->currency->format($this->session->data['shipping_method']['cost']),
```

to

```
'text' => $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($this->session->data['shipping_method']['cost'], $this->session->data['shipping_method']['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax'))),
```

We're just using the tax class to add the shipping tax into the displayed total based on your ***"Display Prices With Tax"*** setting.

Please note, the shipping estimator and shipping charge options in checkout will not be affected by the above changes and will still be displayed without tax as usual - only once you have selected a shipping method and you are looking at the total in the totals section of your cart summary will it be affected.  If you want to change the shipping charges to include tax in the estimator and during checkout process there would be other files involved.

Now to include the *untaxed shipping total* in the displayed subtotal you can edit **catalog/model/total/sub_total.php** and change:

```
'text' => $this->currency->format($sub_total),
```

to

```
'text' => $this->currency->format($sub_total + (isset($this->session->data['shipping_method']['cost']) ? $this->session->data['shipping_method']['cost'] : 0)),
```

Answer (score 0):

Those using OpenCart 2.x might install [this vQmod](https://gist.github.com/apeschar/9e5333b446bfc791fc67059ceedd8e0c).

It applies tax-inclusive prices for the subtotal, the shipping costs, and the shipping costs applied by the Automatic Shipping module, if installed.

For information about using vQmod, see [instructions on installing vQmod](https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/wiki/Installing-vQmod-on-OpenCart).